# Can rigid foam insulation board be installed on wet walls?

Tags: crawlspace, basement-insulation

In the middle of a room addition; block foundation crawl space just built.  I was planning on installing rigid foam board to the interior walls before the framing begins by using a powder activated gun with nails and washers.  Can I do this while the walls are wet and leave it exposed to rain?

Comment: It would probably be a good place for moud.  Moud likes dark damp places.  Besides that little problem you can add the foam.

Comment: Well concrete block is always going to hold moisture.

Comment: Give that stuff a flame test before you decide on it.  A lot of it is *scary*.

Comment: The state code has numbers and the energy department has certificates of testing. Easier than I thought to find the testing figures.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have the roof on the addition, DO NOT install the solid insulation.  A little moisture and humidity is ok, but if it rains on the insulation panels it can take forever for the water to seep out.

Be patient and have the new space dried in before attaching insulation panels.

Comment: I could install the panels, then seal the top with expanding foam. I could then scrape it level for the joists to be installed on the block. Also tape the joint between panels. Can foam would prevent water from being behind the foam board right?

Comment: "Can foam would prevent water from being behind the foam board right? –" 
Maybe...maybe not depending on how hard and driven the rain.  All I can tell you is common practice where I am (Fla) is to put up the panels after dry in.